# Report Tekton pipeline status to GitLab regardless if pipeline failed or succeeded (using gitlab-set-status Task)

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, continuous-integration, tekton, openshift-pipelines

We're already using [the `gitlab-set-status` Task from Tekton Hub](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/gitlab-set-status) to report our Tekton Pipeline's status back into our GitLab instance (here's [our EKS setup & Tekton installment](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks) and [a example project on gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot)). Our [`pipeline.yml`](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/pipelines/pipeline.yml) looks like this and currently reports the `STATE` success every time the Tekton Pipeline runs:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: buildpacks-test-pipeline
spec:
  params:
    - name: IMAGE
      type: string
      description: image URL to push
    - name: SOURCE_URL
      type: string
      description: A git repo url where the source code resides.
    - name: REPO_PATH_ONLY
      type: string
      description: GitLab group & repo name only (e.g. jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot)
    - name: SOURCE_REVISION
      description: The branch, tag or SHA to checkout.
      default: ""
    - name: GITLAB_HOST
      type: string
      description: Your GitLabs host only (e.g. gitlab.com)
    - name: TEKTON_DASHBOARD_HOST
      type: string
      description: The Tekton dashboard host name only

  workspaces:
    - name: source-workspace # Directory where application source is located. (REQUIRED)
    - name: cache-workspace # Directory where cache is stored (OPTIONAL)
  tasks:
    - name: fetch-repository # This task fetches a repository from github, using the `git-clone` task you installed
      taskRef:
        name: git-clone
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: source-workspace
      params:
        - name: url
          value: "$(params.SOURCE_URL)"
        - name: revision
          value: "$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"
        - name: subdirectory
          value: ""
        - name: deleteExisting
          value: "true"
    - name: buildpacks # This task uses the `buildpacks` task to build the application
      taskRef:
        name: buildpacks
      runAfter:
        - fetch-repository
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: source-workspace
        - name: cache
          workspace: cache-workspace
      params:
        - name: APP_IMAGE
          value: "$(params.IMAGE)"
        - name: BUILDER_IMAGE
          value: paketobuildpacks/builder:base # This is the builder we want the task to use (REQUIRED)
    - name: report-pipeline-end-to-gitlab
      taskRef:
        name: "gitlab-set-status"
      runAfter:
        - buildpacks
      params:
        - name: "STATE"
          value: "success"
        - name: "GITLAB_HOST_URL"
          value: "$(params.GITLAB_HOST)"
        - name: "REPO_FULL_NAME"
          value: "$(params.REPO_PATH_ONLY)"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_NAME"
          value: "gitlab-api-secret"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY"
          value: "token"
        - name: "SHA"
          value: "$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"
        - name: "TARGET_URL"
          value: "$(params.TEKTON_DASHBOARD_HOST)/#/namespaces/default/pipelineruns/$(context.pipelineRun.name)"
        - name: "CONTEXT"
          value: "tekton-pipeline"
        - name: "DESCRIPTION"
          value: "Finished building your commit in Tekton"
```

How can we enhance our Tekton Pipeline to report the status correctly and regardless of any failure or success to GitLab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In v0.14 Tekton introduced the so called `finally` Tasks](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/releases/tag/v0.14.0), which run at the end of every `Pipeline` - regardless which Task failed or succeeded. [As the docs state](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#adding-finally-to-the-pipeline):

> finally tasks are guaranteed to be executed in parallel after all PipelineTasks under tasks have completed regardless of success or error.

In general `finally` tasks look like this:

```yaml
spec:
  tasks:
    - name: tests
      taskRef:
        name: integration-test
  finally:
    - name: cleanup-test
      taskRef:
        name: cleanup
```

**But how do we create the corresponding `STATE` in our `gitlab-set-status` Task?** With [using `when` expressions inside our  `finally` tasks](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#guard-finally-task-execution-using-when-expressions) we can run our `gitlab-set-status` Task based on [the overall Pipeline status (or Aggregate Pipeline status)](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#when-expressions-using-aggregate-execution-status-of-tasks-in-finally-tasks):

```
finally:
  - name: notify-any-failure # executed only when one or more tasks fail
    when:
      - input: $(tasks.status)
        operator: in
        values: ["Failed"]
    taskRef:
      name: notify-failure
```

We grab the [Aggregate Execution Status](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#using-aggregate-execution-status-of-all-tasks) by simply using `$(tasks.status)`. This variable is stated to have those 4 possible status:

- `Succeeded` ("all tasks have succeeded")
- `Completed` ("all tasks completed successfully including one or more skipped tasks")

-> which could be translated into the `gitlab-set-status` Tasks `STATE` value `success`.

- `Failed` ("one ore more tasks failed")
- `None` ("no aggregate execution status available (i.e. none of the above), one or more tasks could be pending/running/cancelled/timedout")

-> which could both be translated into the `gitlab-set-status` Tasks `STATE` value `failed`. For `None` this is only valid, since we're in a `finally task`, since `pending/running` could otherwise also mean that a Pipeline is in a good state.

Having 4 states we need to check in our `when` expressions, do we need to implement a separate finally Task for each of them? No, since luckily the `when` expressions ["values is an array of string values."](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#guard-task-execution-using-when-expressions). So we're able to do

```
  when:
    - input: $(tasks.status)
      operator: in
      values: [ "Failed", "None" ]
```

and

```
  when:
    - input: $(tasks.status)
      operator: in
      values: [ "Succeeded", "Completed" ]
```

Finally this results in our Tekton Pipeline's locking like this (and implementing 2 finally tasks `report-pipeline-failed-to-gitlab` and `report-pipeline-success-to-gitlab`):

```
...
  finally:
    - name: report-pipeline-failed-to-gitlab
      when:
        - input: $(tasks.status)
          operator: in
          values: [ "Failed", "None" ] # see aggregated status https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#using-aggregate-execution-status-of-all-tasks
      taskRef:
        name: "gitlab-set-status"
      params:
        - name: "STATE"
          value: "failed"
        - name: "GITLAB_HOST_URL"
          value: "$(params.GITLAB_HOST)"
        - name: "REPO_FULL_NAME"
          value: "$(params.REPO_PATH_ONLY)"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_NAME"
          value: "gitlab-api-secret"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY"
          value: "token"
        - name: "SHA"
          value: "$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"
        - name: "TARGET_URL"
          value: "$(params.TEKTON_DASHBOARD_HOST)/#/namespaces/default/pipelineruns/$(context.pipelineRun.name)"
        - name: "CONTEXT"
          value: "tekton-pipeline"
        - name: "DESCRIPTION"
          value: "An error occurred building your commit in Tekton"
    - name: report-pipeline-success-to-gitlab
      when:
          - input: $(tasks.status)
            operator: in
            values: [ "Succeeded", "Completed" ] # see aggregated status https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#using-aggregate-execution-status-of-all-tasks
      taskRef:
        name: "gitlab-set-status"
      params:
        - name: "STATE"
          value: "success"
        - name: "GITLAB_HOST_URL"
          value: "$(params.GITLAB_HOST)"
        - name: "REPO_FULL_NAME"
          value: "$(params.REPO_PATH_ONLY)"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_NAME"
          value: "gitlab-api-secret"
        - name: "GITLAB_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY"
          value: "token"
        - name: "SHA"
          value: "$(params.SOURCE_REVISION)"
        - name: "TARGET_URL"
          value: "$(params.TEKTON_DASHBOARD_HOST)/#/namespaces/default/pipelineruns/$(context.pipelineRun.name)"
        - name: "CONTEXT"
          value: "tekton-pipeline"
        - name: "DESCRIPTION"
          value: "Finished building your commit in Tekton"
```

Executing our Tekton Pipeline should now be reported correctly to our GitLab. Failures look like this:

[image]

Succeeded Pipelines look like this:

[image]